# Convert linked list to tree in Java

Tags: java, tree, linked-list, binary-tree

I have to make a conversion from singly, doubly and circular linked list to binary tree.

I have made the singly linked list and I am having trouble understanding how to convert it to tree.

My singly linked list Node is the following:

```
public class Node {
    Node next;

    Object data;

    public Node(Object _data)
    {
        next = null;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node(Object _data, Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
    }
}
```

And this is my singly linked list class:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;


public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = new Node(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }

    public void add(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        head.setData(temp.getData());

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(temp);

        listCount++;
    }

    public void add(Object data, int index)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        head.setData(temp.getData());

        for (int i = 1; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        temp.setNext(current.getNext());

        current.setNext(temp);

        listCount++;
    }

    public Object get(int index)
    {
        if(index <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getNext() == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return current.getData();
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return listCount;
    }

    public boolean remove(int index)
    {
        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Node current = head;

        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getNext() == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

        listCount--;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if(temp.getData().equals(current.getData()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Node inserAfter(Object data, Node n)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = n.getNext();

        temp.setNext(current);
        n.setNext(temp);

        return temp;
    }

    public void rotateLeft()
    {
        Node temp = head;

        if (head != null) {                       //otherwise it is empty list
            if (head.getNext() != null) {           //otherwise it is single item list
                head = head.getNext();
            }
        }

        Node tail;
        if (head.getNext() != null) {
            tail = head.getNext();
        } else {
            tail = head;
        }

        while(tail.getNext() != null)
        {
            if (tail.getNext() != null) {
                tail = tail.getNext();
            }
        }
        tail.setNext(temp);
        temp.setNext(null);
    }

    public void rotateRight()
    {
        Node temp = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            temp = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(head);
        head = current;
        temp.setNext(null);
    }

    public void reverse()
    {
        Node reversedPart = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            Node next = current.next;
            current.next = reversedPart;
            reversedPart = current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = reversedPart;
    }

    public Node copyList(Node source)
    {
        Node copyHead = null;
        Node copyTail = null;

        Node temp = new Node(source);
        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(temp.getData());
            if(copyHead == null)
            {
                copyHead = newNode;
                copyTail = copyHead;
            }
            else
            {
                copyTail.setNext(newNode);
                copyTail = copyTail.getNext();
            }
        }

        return copyHead;
    }

    public Object setDataIndexOf(Object data, int index)
    {
        Node node = nodeAt(index);

        if(node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Object old = node.getData();
            node.setData(data);
            return old;
        }
    }

    public Object dataAt(int index)
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();

        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < index; i ++)
        {
            if(i != index - 1)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        return current.getData();
    }

    public Node nodeAt(int index)
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();

        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(i != index - 1)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        return current;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
            {
                return i;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Object min()
    {
        Integer min = (Integer)head.getData();
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            if((Integer)current.getData() < min)
            {
                min = (Integer)current.getData();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return min;
    }

    public Object max()
    {
        Integer max = (Integer)head.getData();
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            if((Integer)current.getData() > max)
            {
                max = (Integer)current.getData();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return max;
    }

    public void removeSecondAppear(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;

        boolean found = false;

        while(current != null)
        {                       
            if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()) && current.getData() != null)
            {
                if(found == true)
                {
                    previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                    break;
                }
                else if(found == false)
                {
                    found = true;
                }

            }
            else{
                found = false;
            }

            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();
        String output = "";

        while(current != null)
        {
            output += "[" + current.getData().toString() + "]";
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Having the singly linked list created, I have to create a new tree based on the list. I am completely lost and have no idea how to start. Never done something similar before.  Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to implement a binary search tree. I just had a google and there are plenty of example Java implementations you can learn from. Your binary search tree should have an insert method that takes one parameter, ideally an unbounded type but given your list implementation just go with Object for now:

```
public void insert(Object element);
```

Once your BST is built, iterate through your list and add the elements to the tree as follows:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
list.add("baz");
list.add("etc");
BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree(); 
for(Object o:list) {
    bst.add(o);
}
```

Comment: I am reading your comment and I am stuck at the second sentence, what exactly is my 'one'?

Comment: If you're stuck for a sample binary search tree implementation, try this: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/binary-search-tree-implementation-in-java.html before implementing your own based on your lecture notes etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look now. Also, if I may ask, if I want to do the same with tree -> list, the method is pretty much the same except they swap their places?

Comment: @user12831231 the method of adding objects to the collection is pretty much the same, in a list the method is generally called add whilst in a binary tree it's generally called insert. The difference is in the data structure. A linked list has an order n lookup time O(n) whereas a binary tree has a O(log(n)) lookup time. A linkedlist has constant time insert O(1) whereas a binary tree will have O(log(n)) insert.

Comment: complexity isn't much of a problem here, I'm just trying to understand to transformation in this case :)

Comment: @user12831231 cool, then yes, you just want to get the objects from the list and insert them into the binary tree.

Comment: I have tried what you said, and I have one problem. When I do the `for(Object o:list)` it says an error on `list` which says `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterate`.\

Comment: Ah right enough. Just use a for loop. Something like: for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 bst.insert(list.get(i));
}